# Selecting data from datatable

Tags: c#, lambda, datatable

I want to select data from a datatable. Currently I am using an annonymous list.
The datatable looks like this:

```
ID  AMOUNT INVOICE_DATE
```

`1   9,5     06.03.2020`
`2   12,4    06.03.2020`
`1   12,5    07.03.2020`
`2   14,3    07.03.2020`
`3   15      07.03.2020`
`2   17      08.03.2020`
`3   19,2    08.03.2020`
`3   12      08.03.2020`

And the way I have to query is like this:

```
ID  AMOUNT  TOTAL_AMOUNT_SOLD INVOICE_DATE
```

`1   12,5     23                07.03.2020`
`2   14,3     26,7              07.03.2020`
`3   15       15                07.03.2020`
`2   17       43,7              08.03.2020`
`3   31,2     46.2              08.03.2020`

This is my code right now:

```
                var soldInDT = dt.AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(x => x.Field<int>("ID"))
                .Select(grp => new
            {
                ID = grp.FirstOrDefault().Field<int>("ID"),
                AMOUNT = grp.Where(x => x.Field<int>("ID") == grp.Key).Sum(x => x.Field<double>("AMOUNT")),
                TOTAL_AMOUNT_SOLD = grp.Where(x => x.Field<int>("ID") == grp.Key && x.Field<DateTime>("INVOICE_DATE") < startDate).Sum(x => x.Field<double>("AMOUNT")),
                DATE = grp.FirstOrDefault().Field<DateTime>("INVOICE_DATE")
            }).ToList();
```

And is there a faster way to do it than using lambda expressions and those lists?

Comment: Your expected result seems wrong, since you are saying you want to group by `ID` but your expected result has 2 entries of the `ID`s 2 and 3.

Comment: So after removing the group statement the first answer seems incorrect because I can't use `grp.Key` and I should use `ID = grp.Field<int>("ID")` ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
ID = grp.FirstOrDefault().Field<int>("ID")
```

just say

```
ID = grp.Key
```

Instead of

```
grp.Where(x => x.Field<int>("ID") == grp.Key).Sum(x => x.Field<double>("AMOUNT"))
```

just say

```
grp.Sum(x => x.Field<double>("AMOUNT"))
```

Instead of

```
grp.Where(x => x.Field<int>("ID") == grp.Key && x.Field<DateTime>("INVOICE_DATE") < startDate).Sum(x => x.Field<double>("AMOUNT"))
```

just say

```
grp.Where(x => x.Field<DateTime>("INVOICE_DATE") < startDate).Sum(x => x.Field<double>("AMOUNT"))
```